# Regex to match hexadecimal and integer numbers

Tags: regex

We have been tasked with coming up with a regex that matches both integer and hexadecimal numbers (a number starting with '0x' followed by any combination of letters (a-f) and numbers).

Should match:

- 0xa9bf
- 42

Should not match:

- a9bf
- 0xg

What we have tried so far:

```
([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)
```

This does not work however. Any suggestions to how we can improve?

Comment: Try `^([0-9]+|0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)$`. BTW, what do you mean by "This does not work"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. However, your solution works.

Comment: More accurate version is `^([0-9]+|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)$`